# How can I concatenate pytorch tensors or lists in a distributed multi-node setup?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, python-multiprocessing, distributed-system

I am trying to implement something like this for 2 nodes (each node with 2 GPUs):

```
#### Parallel process initiated with torch.distributed.init_process_group()
### All GPUs work in parallel, and generate lists like :
    [20, 0, 1, 17] for GPU0 of node A 
    [1, 2, 3, 4] for GPU1 of node A
    [5, 6, 7, 8] for GPU0 of node B
    [0, 2, 4, 6] for GPU1 of node B
```

I tried

```
torch.distributed.reduce()
```

to get a sum of these 4:

```
[26,  10, 15, 35]
```

But what I want is a concatenated version like this

```
[[20, 0, 1, 17], [1, 2, 3, 4] , [5, 6, 7, 8] , [0, 2, 4, 6]]
```

Or

```
[20, 0, 1, 17, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 2, 4, 6]
```

is also OK with me.

Is it possible to achieve this from torch.distributed?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`dist.all_gather`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributed.html#torch.distributed.all_gather) to do this:

```
import torch
import torch.distributed as dist

q = torch.tensor([20, 0, 1, 17]) # generated on each gpu (with different values) as you mentioned
all_q = [torch.zeros_like(q) for _ in range(world_size)] # world_size is the total number of gpu processes you are running. 4 in your case.
all_q = dist.all_gather(all_q, q)
```

`all_q` would then have the following:

`[torch.tensor([20, 0, 1, 17]), torch.tensor([1, 2, 3, 4]), torch.tensor([5, 6, 7, 8]), torch.tensor([0, 2, 4, 6])]`

You can then use `torch.cat` to collapse all elements into one array if you like.

You can use [`dist.all_gather_multigpu`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributed.html#torch.distributed.all_gather_multigpu) if you list of lists of tensors.